Microchip XC8 - Unexpected data memory increase after deletion of variable
I am currently optimising and streamlining development code in preparation for release.
Hardware and compiler specifics as follows:

PIC18F46J11, MPLABX, XC8 - V2.45, C99, Optimization level 1

See below (heavily truncated(I.P)) code of area of interest.
DEV CODE:
    unsigned long Adc18;
    unsigned long ReadAdc;
    unsigned long AvgAdc;

    ReadAdc=Adc18;
    AvgAdc = AvgAdc + ReadAdc;

Estimated memory usage: 2988 bytes DATA (RAM), 57753 bytes PROGRAM (ROM)
STREAMLINED CODE:
    unsigned long Adc18;
    unsigned long AvgAdc;

    AvgAdc = AvgAdc + Adc18;

Estimated memory usage: 3022 bytes DATA (RAM), 57651 bytes PROGRAM (ROM)
Question: What could cause the DATA usage increase in a scenario such as this? I  expected PROGRAM memory to decrease as we have both removed a variable of type long and associated code.
This is my first question on this platform so please forgive any errors in formatting.
Thanks in advance!

Generate and examine the map file: https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/oxy/GUID-BB433107-FD4E-4D28-BB58-9D4A58955B1A-en-US-6/GUID-374557E7-E7C4-4AE6-A568-5FF8576076AB.html It provides the full information on the memory allocation in your program.

What does "estimated memory usage" mean?  After compiling and linking, the memory usage should be exactly deterministic. Generate the map file for each and compare.

When checking the map, you might find static RAM usage is actually lower. I'm afraid that "estimated memory usage" includes stack usage, and your "optimization" needs more RAM for stack than it saves statically.

Generally, do not hand-optimize code, trust the compiler. Only if you don't meet requirements, carefully think about what to change. Such micro optimizations in source lead commonly to just micro saves. Usually you need to invent new algorithms.

Thanks for the recommendations on checking the .map file, indeed there were collateral differences in memory allocation across the map in addition to the obvious program memory reduction. Understoo

OK, understood that MPLABX memory usage indication is exact.

You might want to write an own answer, this is fine. After some time you will mark it as "accepted" so that future visitors with a similar issue see this solved issue upfront in the list. Please make sure to include helpful details, see [answer].

You have truncated the code so much, that no code at all would have been the same.  Please follow How to create a minimal, reproducible example.
